# What is the best way for open and close some div in Angular?

Tags: angular

I need function with MouseEvent for open and close calendar.
If clicked on input, calendar should be open and close when click outside calendar.
With open calendar everything OK, but problem is with target.className, because user can click on many elements of calendar and I don't want to write the same class everywhere. It will be awful.
Problem is that clicked on calendar made it also closed.

I want to close calendar only when I click outside calendar.

parent component HTML:

```
<div id="dateFrom">
    <svg viewBox="0 0 24 24"><path d="M22.502 13.5v8.25a.75.75 0 0 1-.75.75h-19.5a.75.75 0 0 1-.75-.75V5.25a.75.75 0 0 1 .75-.75h19.5a.75.75 0 0 1 .75.75v8.25zm1.5 0V5.25A2.25 2.25 0 0 0 21.752 3h-19.5a2.25 2.25 0 0 0-2.25 2.25v16.5A2.25 2.25 0 0 0 2.252 24h19.5a2.25 2.25 0 0 0 2.25-2.25V13.5zm-23.25-3h22.5a.75.75 0 0 0 0-1.5H.752a.75.75 0 0 0 0 1.5zM7.502 6V.75a.75.75 0 0 0-1.5 0V6a.75.75 0 0 0 1.5 0zm10.5 0V.75a.75.75 0 0 0-1.5 0V6a.75.75 0 0 0 1.5 0z"></path></svg>
    <input class="clickForOpenCalendar1" autocomplete="off" readonly type="text" value="{{fromDate | date: 'dd.MM.yy'}}">
  </div>
<div id="dateTo">
    <svg viewBox="0 0 24 24"><path d="M22.502 13.5v8.25a.75.75 0 0 1-.75.75h-19.5a.75.75 0 0 1-.75-.75V5.25a.75.75 0 0 1 .75-.75h19.5a.75.75 0 0 1 .75.75v8.25zm1.5 0V5.25A2.25 2.25 0 0 0 21.752 3h-19.5a2.25 2.25 0 0 0-2.25 2.25v16.5A2.25 2.25 0 0 0 2.252 24h19.5a2.25 2.25 0 0 0 2.25-2.25V13.5zm-23.25-3h22.5a.75.75 0 0 0 0-1.5H.752a.75.75 0 0 0 0 1.5zM7.502 6V.75a.75.75 0 0 0-1.5 0V6a.75.75 0 0 0 1.5 0zm10.5 0V.75a.75.75 0 0 0-1.5 0V6a.75.75 0 0 0 1.5 0z"></path></svg>
    <input class="clickForOpenCalendar2" autocomplete="off" readonly type="text" value="{{toDate | date: 'dd.MM.yy'}}">
  </div>
<div class="calendar clickForOpenCalendar1" [ngClass]="{visibleCalendar: showCalendar==myEnum.first || showCalendar==myEnum.second}">
    <app-calendar
      (finalFromDate)="calendarFrom($event)"
      (finalToDate)="calendarTo($event)"
    ></app-calendar>
  </div>
```

child calendar Component DOM:

```
<div>
 <div>
  <div>
```

clicked element on child never has necessary class for my function

parent TS:

```
 @HostListener("document:click", ['$event'])   clicked(event: MouseEvent) {
    console.log(event.target)
    const target = event.target as HTMLElement
    const str:String = target.className
    if(str.includes("clickForOpenCalendar1")) this.showCalendar = calendarStatus.first;
    else if(str.includes("clickForOpenCalendar2")) this.showCalendar = calendarStatus.second
    else this.showCalendar = calendarStatus.hidden   }
```

I hope you understand my idea and I will be grateful for help me with find best solution for this behavour.

Comment: can you not use [datepicker](https://material.angular.io/components/datepicker/overview)?

Comment: I need to use my own calendar

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For closing you can use https://www.npmjs.com/package/ng-click-outside package or write your own code by looking at source code. Dont forget to star) I am not author of package.

Answer (score 0):

I'm frankenstein and I created so ugly monster like that:

```
@HostListener("document:click", ['$event'])
  clicked(event: MouseEvent) {
    const target = event.target as HTMLElement
    const myClass = target.getAttribute("class")
    const myParentClass = target.parentElement.getAttribute("class")

    if(myClass != null){
      if(myClass.includes("clickForOpenCalendar1")) this.showCalendar = calendarStatus.first;
      else if(myClass.includes("clickForOpenCalendar2")) this.showCalendar = calendarStatus.second
      else if (!myClass.includes("calendarOpen")) this.showCalendar = calendarStatus.hidden
    }
    else if(myParentClass != null && !myParentClass.includes("calendarOpen")) this.showCalendar = calendarStatus.hidden
    else if (myClass == null && myParentClass == null) this.showCalendar = calendarStatus.hidden
  }
```

What do you think? If works, it's ok? Or it's really messy in here?

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-ask).